# what i am doing wrong? code below not copying last record of structured data from .dat file to another .dat file in C

Tags: c, file-io, structure

```
#include<conio.h>

#include<stdio.h>

struct stud

{
  int rollno;
  char name[10];
  char add[10];
};

void main()
{
    struct stud st;

    FILE *fp,*fpp;

    char another='y',ch;

    int a,choice,i;

    printf("***Press 1 to Add record/Create database***\n");

    scanf("%d",&a);

    if(a==1)    /*recording data begins here*/
    {
        fflush(stdin);
        printf("ADD or CREATE NEW?(a/c): ");    /*prompt message to add new record to existing database or to create new database*/
        scanf("%c",&ch);

     if(ch=='a')    /*appending file*/
     {
      add:

      ch='a';

      fp=fopen("Studm.dat","ab");

      while(another=='y' || another=='Y')
      {
        fflush(stdin);

        printf("Enter RollNo. Name & Address\n");

        scanf("%d%s%s",&st.rollno,st.name,&st.add);

        fwrite(&st,sizeof(st),1,fp);

        fflush(stdin);

        printf("\nAdd another record?(y/n): ");    /*prompt message to add another record*/
        scanf("%c",&another);

      }

     }

        if(ch=='c')    /*to create new data file*/
        {

        fp=fopen("Studm.dat","wb");

        printf("Enter RollNo. Name & Address\n");

        scanf("%d%s%s",&st.rollno,st.name,&st.add);

        fwrite(&st,sizeof(st),1,fp);

        fflush(stdin);

        printf("\nAdd another record?(y/n): ");

        scanf("%c",&another);

        fclose(fp);

        if(another=='y' || another=='Y')
        {

         goto add;   /*go to the append file block above*/
        }


    }

      fclose(fp);

    }
```

whenever i open source file in text editor all the names(character data) given are visible, that means storing and recording block is working perfectly.

```
    fflush(stdin);

    printf("\n\nCopying data from studm.dat to stud1.data\n\n");

    fp=fopen("Studm.dat","rb");

    fpp=fopen("Stud1.dat","wb");

    while(fread(&st,sizeof(st),1,fp)==1)    /*loop block to copy data*/
    {
        fflush(stdin);    /*tried every place for flushing the buffer, before and after fwrite with in the loop*/

        fwrite(&st,sizeof(st),1,fpp);

    }
    fclose(fp);

    fclose(fpp);
```

like source file i opened target file in text editor after executing the whole program code records up to the second last record were there.

```
    printf("\n\nCopying done now reading data from file Stud1.dat\n\n");

    fpp=fopen("Stud1.dat","rb");

    while(fread(&st,sizeof(st),1,fp)==1)
    {

     printf("%d %s %s\n",st.rollno,st.name,st.add);

    }

    fclose(fpp);

    getch();
 }
```

i think problem is in copying block, but i don't know whether it's something related to buffer or i have coded wrong or a bug.

Comment: Do consider closing the files.

Comment: i have also tried flushing the buffer but still the last record is not copied from the source file to target file

Comment: Asking a question doesn't even have enough details to put an appropriate caption.

Comment: @grhegde now have a look please i have given the whole code

Comment: @Lion is that much detailing is enough?

Answer (score 0):

You can try using feof() that might solve the problem :

```
while (1)
{
 fread ( &st , sizeof ( st ) , 1 , fp);
 fwrite ( &st , sizeof(st) , 1 , fpp);
 if( feof(fp) ) 
  break;
}
```

Comment: after using feof second last record is copied twice

Comment: after using feof the second last record is copied twice

Comment: check out now I had edited the code. 
feof() returns true AFTER you try to read past the end of file.
So this code should work better

Answer (score 0):

I have made some changes to avoid complexity. **And for God's sake don't use goto label in your code to replace loops.**

Sorry about multiple edits.
**Here is the final working code.** Just compile and execute.

```
#include<stdio.h>

struct stud {
    int rollno;
    char name[100];
    char add[100];
};

void main() {
    struct stud st;
    FILE *fp, *fpp;
    int a, i, i_ret_val, another;
    printf("***Press 1 to Add record/Create database***\n");
    scanf("%d", &a);
    fflush(stdin);
    if (a == 1) /*recording data begins here*/
    {
        /*Since you are using the same file name throughout two cases are not
         * required for adding and creating. Can achieve create in append mode fopen*/
        fp = fopen("Studm.dat", "ab");
        do {
            fflush(stdin);
            printf("Enter RollNo. Name & Address\n");
            scanf("%d%s%s", &st.rollno, &st.name, &st.add);
            printf("Fwrite returned %d\n", fwrite(&st, sizeof(st), 1, fp));
            printf("\nAdd another record?1 for yes: \n"); /*prompt message to add another record*/
            scanf("%d", &another);
        } while (another == 1);
        fclose(fp);
    }
    printf("\nNow Copying the file.\n");
    fp = fopen("Studm.dat", "rb");
    fpp = fopen("Stud1.dat", "wb");
    i_ret_val = fread(&st, sizeof(st), 1, fp);
    while (i_ret_val == 1) {
        i_ret_val = fwrite(&st, sizeof(st), 1, fpp);
        i_ret_val = fread(&st, sizeof(st), 1, fp);
    }
    fclose(fp);
    fclose(fpp);
    printf("\n\nCopying done. Now reading data from file Stud1.dat\n\n");
    fpp = fopen("Stud1.dat", "rb");
    i_ret_val = fread(&st, sizeof(st), 1, fpp);
    printf("\nRetrieved from database\n");
    while (i_ret_val == 1) {
        printf("Roll No: %d, Name: %s, Address:%s\n", st.rollno, st.name,
                st.add);
        i_ret_val = fread(&st, sizeof(st), 1, fpp);
    }
    fclose(fpp);
}
```

Comment: ok, suppose i have recorded data for 5 students on running the code first time now if i don't want to append next time how i will be able to clear previous data and start fresh if i don't have any option for opening file in "rb" mode, i have traced the code goto label is not disturbing the flow of execution and at last i am not having problem in recording the data in source file, the code only not copying my last record from source to target file.

Comment: ok. Just wanted to make the code look more easy. So i removed the create option. I agree that goto was not disturbing the code flow. But it makes it harder to read. And about the problem, I am looking into the copy part. I'll edit the answer once i am done.

Comment: it worked, but code creates fresh database once at the first run and keeps on appending records every time i run it again, i also want to add a code segment for creating a fresh database file i.e, clear previous records and starts from fresh

Comment: That should be an easy change.